# How to change or hide the word 'pages' in the reference list using bibtex?

Tags: bibtex

I am using bibtex to generate a reference list. Given those .tex and .bib files

test.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{german}

\begin{document}
    \cite{test}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{literature}
\end{document}
```

literature.bib

```
@inbook{test,
author = {test},
title = {test},
year = {test},
pages = {1--2}
}
```

the result of running pdflatex, bibtex and pdflatex is similar to

> [1]
>
> LITERATUR
>
> [1] test. *test*, pages 1–2. test.

Note that using `\usepackage{german}` changes References to **Literatur**, while **pages** is untouched.

I would prefer to use **S.** instead of **pages**, but if it is only possible to hide **pages** completely, that's fine as well. How can I accomplish this?

Edit:

Desired Output:

> [1]
>
> LITERATUR
>
> [1] test. *test*, S. 1–2. test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks to me as if the plaindin.bst, in `http://mirror.ctan.org/bibliography/bibtex/contrib/german/din1505.zip` does what you want.

... at the very least, its `pages` function uses `S`

the real answer, i assume, would be to switch to biblatex (which is designed to do this sort of thing), but i'm not the person to help you there.